# tcpdump difference between ip host hostname | ip and host hostname

Tags: wireshark, packet, tcpdump, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

In `tcpdump`, which is the difference between the following two commands? I tried to understand but they seems pretty much the same to me.

```
tcpdump ip host google.com
```

and

```
tcpdump ip and host google.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.  If you compare the packet-matching code, generated by including the `-d` option, then you can see that they produce identical results:

```
tcpdump -d "ip host google.com"
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x800           jt 2    jf 7
(002) ld       [26]
(003) jeq      #0x8efa41ae      jt 6    jf 4
(004) ld       [30]
(005) jeq      #0x8efa41ae      jt 6    jf 7
(006) ret      #262144
(007) ret      #0

tcpdump -d "ip and host google.com"
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x800           jt 2    jf 7
(002) ld       [26]
(003) jeq      #0x8efa41ae      jt 6    jf 4
(004) ld       [30]
(005) jeq      #0x8efa41ae      jt 6    jf 7
(006) ret      #262144
(007) ret      #0
```